# Adjusting rule lengths in fncychap

Tags: fncychap

I'm using the fncychap package, option Sonny, which sets rules above and below the chapter title.  Because of the way I set section headings, I'd like to extend the rules 1in to the left to align with those headings.  Is this possible?
[image]

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\usepackage[calcwidth]{titlesec}

\setlength{\textwidth}{5.0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.5in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{1.5in}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\Large\bfseries}{\hspace*{-1in}\thesection}{1em}{}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One}
\kant[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `titlesec`, it would make sense to style the chapter this way, too. The following approximates the style you are using, although you may wish to adjust it slightly for an exact match.

I also use `geometry` rather than setting the page dimensions manually. As I mentioned when answering an earlier question, setting them manually is not advisable.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
% Don't set layout manually
\geometry{letterpaper,width=5in,left=2.5in,asymmetric,verbose}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\Large\sffamily}{\filleft
  \MakeUppercase{\chaptername}\quad{\Huge\thechapter}}{40pt}{\titlerule[.5pt]\vspace{10pt}\filleft
  \MakeUppercase}[\vspace{10pt}{\titlerule[.5pt]}]
\titlespacing*{\section}{-25.4mm}{*4}{*1.5}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{-25.4mm}{*6}{*10}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{{\itshape #1}}}% \it ought not be used with LaTeX 2e!!
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[CO]{\rightmark}
\fancyheadoffset[lh]{25.4mm}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One}
\kant[1]
\section{Section Two}
\kant[2]
\section{Section Three}
\kant[3]
\section{Section Four}
\kant[4-8]
\end{document}
```

[image: mangling titles for special effects]